# Indicators of Ras binding domain (RBD) activity in Ras effector proteins?

Tags: biochemistry, proteins

[Ras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ras_subfamily) family based small GTPase proteins usually have a Ras binding domain (RBD) in their effector downstream proteins like [Raf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAF_kinase). Roughly Ras proteins cycle between active(GTP-bound situation) and inactive(GDP-bound) states. So what information is passed onto RBD when Ras protein is active in a Ras:Raf complex. It is well known that Switch-I , Switch-II root mean square fluctuations(RMSF) of inactive Ras protein is very high. In the active Ras case the Switch-I RMSF falls by making that loop rigid.

So my question is that is there any observables like RMSF of RBD region indicate the "activity" of effector molecule(like that of Raf). In other words how do I understand that the RBD region is active/inactive (say from simulation perspective or experimental perspective) ?

Please suggest me any related references or links.